# Tomcat 6 Default Memory Allocation Settings

Tags: tomcat, memory

Does anyone know or know how to find the default values for the various memory allocation-related parameters (-Xms, -Xms, -XX:PermSize, -XX:MaxPermSize) for Tomcat version 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell the defaults should be the same as for any server JVM. Are you using the default Sun/Oracle JDK, version 6?

If so you could check the default values.

### Java 8

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

[Garbage Collector Ergonomics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html)

[HotSpot Tuning Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/index.html)

### Java 6

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html

Of course, if this particular Tomcat install is new to you remember to check the actual JVM parameters using `ps auxwwe` (if using Linux) and its init scripts in case someone set CATALINA_OPTS or JAVA_OPTS, etc.